# How to add a root to an existing XML which doesn't have a single root tag

Tags: python, xml, parse-error

I'm having one XML file which doesn't have a single root tag. I want to add a new Root tag to this XML file.

Below is the existing XML:

```
<A>
    <Val>123</Val>
</A>

<B>
    <Val1>456</Val1>
</B>
```

Now I want to add a Root tag 'X', so the final XML will look like:

```
<X>
  <A>
     <Val>123</Val>
  </A>

  <B>
     <Val1>456</Val1>
  </B>
</X>
```

I've tried using the below python code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET  
root = ET.parse(Input_FilePath).getroot()   
newroot = ET.Element("X")    
newroot.insert(0, root)    
tree = ET.ElementTree(newroot)    
tree.write(Output_FilePath)
```

But at the first line I'm getting the below error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 4, column 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your can do in without xml parsers.
If your know that root tag missing, you can add it by such way.

```
with open('test.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

with open('test.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write("<x>\n" + data + "\n</x>")
    f.close()
```

If dont know, your can check it by:

```
   import re
   if re.match(u"\s*<x>.*</x>", text, re.S) != None:
      #do something   
      pass
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments by @kjhughes, the XML spec requires that a document must have a single root element.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

node = ET.parse(Input_FilePath)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 4, column 0
```

You'll need to read the file manually and add the tags yourself:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

with open(Input_FilePath) as f:
    xml_string = '<X>' + f.read() + '</X>'

node = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
```