# How to add a root to an XML file?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xmlroot

I have an xml file in the following format:

```
<event time="0.0" type="actend" person="770885_2_Person" link="271711" actType="other"  />
    <event time="0.0" type="departure" person="770885_2_Person" link="271711" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="0.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="770885_2_Person" vehicle="770885_2_Person"  />
    <event time="0.0" type="vehicle enters traffic" person="770885_2_Person" link="271711" vehicle="770885_2_Person" networkMode="car" relativePosition="1.0"  />
    <event time="1.0" type="left link" link="271711"  />
    <event time="1.0" type="entered link" link="271715" vehicle="770885_2_Person"  />
    <event time="15.0" type="left link" link="271715"  />
    <event time="15.0" type="entered link" link="535413" vehicle="770885_2_Person"  />
    <event time="17.0" type="left link" link="535413"  />
    <event time="17.0" type="entered link" link="813064" vehicle="770885_2_Person"  />
    <event time="19.0" type="left link" link="813064"  />
    <event time="19.0" type="entered link" link="813066" vehicle="770885_2_Person"  />
    <event time="22.0" type="left link" link="813066"  />
    <event time="22.0" type="entered link" link="813068" vehicle="770885_2_Person"  />
    <event time="23.0" type="actend" person="368018_2_Person" link="614790" actType="other"  />
    <event time="23.0" type="departure" person="368018_2_Person" link="614790" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="23.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="368018_2_Person" vehicle="368018_2_Person"  />
    <event time="23.0" type="vehicle enters traffic" person="368018_2_Person" link="614790" vehicle="368018_2_Person" networkMode="car" relativePosition="1.0"  />
    <event time="24.0" type="left link" link="614790"  />
....
```

A root node is missing, thus, when I do `treeEvents = et.parse(file_occup_xml)` I get error related to the absence of the root (when I add a root manually the above parse works fine).
So i looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853644/python-xml-parseerror-junk-after-document-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714832/python-how-to-add-root-node-to-an-xml), however, in both cases I cannot actually do the `parse()` command since there is no root.

Do I miss something here? How can I then add a root on that XML file?

Comment: "when I add a root manually the above parse works fine" - so do what you did manually but do it in python then post back here if you have problems.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel by manually I mean that I simply copy-pasted the required root into the xml file and then the```treeEvents = et.parse(file_occup_xml)``` works. But, I don't want to do it "manually" I want Python to add the root on the first line (and close it at the end).

Comment: Basic file input-output operations should do it. Most tutorials should cover that topic. SO is not a replacement for tutorials.

Comment: An XML file is just a text file so [basic file operations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) are all you need.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55455486/407651

Comment: Technically, by definition XML contains a root. So, check how that root-less markup was created. Usually, non-well-formed markup occurs due to string building of XML. Be sure to always use compliant DOM libraries like `etree`, `lxml`, and other libraries in other languages. See [What's so bad about building XML with string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034611/1422451)